# Express envia a resposta antes de ter toda a informação que precisa

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Estou tentando fazer uma ferramenta apenas para meu uso pessoal, é uma ferramenta de pesquisa WHOIS / DNS, e uso a API de outro site para fazer isso.

A URL que estou usando para fazer a solicitação é: http://www.isptools.com.br/tool.whois_json.php?query=

E você pode colocar o que quiser após a URL que será consultada.

Meu programa coleta os dados com sucesso, mas ele envia de volta o "res" antes que as informações do whois estejam de volta, então a variável é Indefinida.

```
function whois(ip) {
    var content;
    fetch('http://www.isptools.com.br/tool.whois_json.php?query='+ip)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => content = data)
        .then((content) => {
            console.log(content); // returns the actual data
            return content; // I have two of these just for testing purposes
        })
    return content; // :)
}

app.get("/query/:type/:ip",(req,res) => {
    var type = req.params.type;
    var ip = req.params.ip;
    var dados = 'nada';
    if (type === 'whois') {
        try {
            dados = whois(ip);
        } catch(err){
            console.log("Um erro ocorreu ao tentar fazer um query de WHOIS:\n"+err);
        }
    }

    console.log(dados); //returns undefined.
    res.send(dados); // returns a blank html
});
```

Como posso fazer isso da maneira correta? Eu não faço ideia.

Muito obrigado!

Comment: I'm sorry if I did something wrong on the posting part or something idiot on the code... Why I'm betting down voted?

Comment: No [pt.so] você deve perguntar em **Português**

Comment: faz todo sentido, desculpe... Eu não tinha visto que eu estava no brasileiro... Mudei a linguagem da pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa manipular os dados de resposta dentro da *callback* de resolução da chamada a API.

Lembre-se que essas callbacks não são executadas de forma sequencial, elas são disparadas por eventos, então não tem como garantir que elas conseguirão inicializar uma variável antes que a sua função retorne essa variável.

Esse tópico de assincronismo é um pouco extenso, e você pode encontrar dezenas de respostas e tópicos a respeito disso, então não vou perder muito tempo detalhando a fundo o funcionamento, vou sugerir algumas formas de resolução:

**Retorne a promise da sua função ao invés do valor**

Dessa forma você consegue criar uma callback dentro da sua rota `/query/:type/:ip` para tratar quando invocar o `res.send`:

```
function whois(ip) {
    return fetch('http://www.isptools.com.br/tool.whois_json.php?query='+ip)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(content => {
            console.log(content);
            return content;
        });
}

app.get('/query/:type/:ip', (req, res) => {
    const type = req.params.type;
    const ip = req.params.ip;
    const promise = type === 'whois' ? whois(ip) : Promise.resolve();

    promise
        .then(dados => {
            console.log(dados);
            res.send(dados);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Um erro ocorreu ao tentar fazer um query de WHOIS:\n'+err);
            res.status(500).send({ error: 'Algo deu errado' });
        });
});
```

**Utilize async e await para escrever o código de forma imperativa**

Esse é um recurso bastante documentado que vale a pena estudar:

```
async function whois(ip) {
    const res = await fetch('http://www.isptools.com.br/tool.whois_json.php?query='+ip);
    const content = await res.json();

    console.log(content);
    return content;
}

app.get('/query/:type/:ip', async (req, res) => {
    const type = req.params.type;
    const ip = req.params.ip;

    try {
        const dados = type === 'whois' ? await whois(ip) : undefined;
        console.log(dados);
        res.send(dados);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Um erro ocorreu ao tentar fazer um query de WHOIS:\n'+err);
        res.status(500).send({ error: 'Algo deu errado' });
    }
});
```

---

Ambas abordagens são equivalentes.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! era exatamente isso que eu precisava saber, vou pesquisar mais sobre o assunto a partir disso =)